# Layout incorrect at end of awakeFromNib - requires resize to correct it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an awakeFormNib function which adds some subviews. It is not using auto-layout. Normally it appears perfecty. On some machines it appears with one of the subviews too small. As soon as I resize the window (with the mouse) it all lays out perfectly. It seems that seme layout operation is happening before awakeFromNib on those machines (at a guess). I have fonnd a very inelegant workaround where at the end of awakeFromNib I call setFrame on one of the subviews to change its size by one pixel. This must have the same effect as resizing with the mouse, since it causes the layout to appear as expected.

So my question is this: Is rhere a function I can call on the window or it subviews that causes the same layout operations that would be caused by a resize (with th emouse) or by changing the frame size in code. i have tried calling setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay: but no success.

Answer (score 4):

You need to refactor all of your framing code from `awakeFromNib` to:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];

}
```

Why?

Because this is the method that is called when the view knows what it's size dimensions are. This method will also be called whenever there is a change to your view's frame.